# Appending javascript to div with jquery

Tags: jquery, append, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to append the following javascript to a div that will appear when the user presses the ESC key. I can't seem to get the JavaScript to display the value of the javascript being used:

```
    $("#json").hide();
    $(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
         $("#json").append("<script type="text/javascript"> + "window.location.href = '/editorialPortal' + '?' + this.id + '=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" + "</" + script>").toggle();
    }
});
```

I'm not sure where I'm missing string escaping or a quotation mark.

Comment: What? You want to go to a new page when the user presses escape?

Comment: No, that JavaScript pulls the current URI plus another parameter from a dropdown, which is used to provide results from the dropdown selection. This javascript should show the current URI based on that selection, which is being hidden from the basic user.

Comment: Well `this` doesn't refer to a dropdown, it refers to the `document` - and `window.location.href` is used to change the page location, and `toggle` is used to hide and show an element... there's a lot wrong. What is your end goal?

Comment: Ignore the dropdown selection part(I was explaining the use of that URI). The idea is to simply grab the current URI and append it to the div that is being triggered on keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with the quotes:

```
$('#json').append('<' + script type="text/javascript">window.location.href = "/editorialPortal?' + this.id + '=' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value + '"  </' + 'script>').toggle();
```

In this example, I use single quotes in defining strings, so the double quotes can be used inside it.

Also, be sure to include jQuery in your fiddles. The above code works except that it errors on the undefined variables `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` and `this.id`. Breaking up of the script tags is to make jsfiddle happy.

Answer (score 1):

Try e.which rather than e.keyCode

Also, since you opened the string with double quotes, you cannot use double quotes in the string (open it with single quotes, and only use single-quotes when you want to use ' + ' or close the whole string).